# SUM subcategory into one

Tags: sql, sum, teradata

I am looking at add a date range to the below query.  Any help would be fantastic thank you in advance.

```
select (case when col2 in ('Commercial', 'Non-commercial') then 'Commercial'
             when col2 in ('OEM', 'CA-OEM') then 'OEM'
             else 'col2'
        end),
       sum(col4) as col4
from t
group by (case when col2 in ('Commercial', 'Non-commercial') then 'Commercial'
               when col2 in ('OEM', 'CA-OEM') then 'OEM'
               else 'col2'
          end);
```

The date is shown as below in SQL

```
SELECT Customer_type,TRX_DATE (FORMAT 'YYYY-MM') (CHAR(7)) AS BATCH_DATE_MONTH
WHERE CAST(TRX_DATE AS DATE FORMAT 'mm/dd/yyyy') >= '02-01-2016'
Group BY 1,2
ORDER BY 1

    Customer_Type   BATCH_DATE_MONTH    Number_Invoices Billed_Amount
1   Commercial-Non-OEM  2016-02 48  382458.92
2   Commercial- Non-OEM 2016-05 77  7646263.67
5   Non-OEM 2016-05 81  11841927.23
6   Non-OEM 2016-02 25  1630832.81
9   OEM 2016-04 68  280264011.01
10  OEM 2016-03 74  277606302.23
13  CA-OEM  2016-03 23  947248.13
14  CA-OEM  2016-05 17  420363.61
17  US-OEM  2016-04 35  4627887.87
18  US-OEM  2016-03 40  6450226.49
19  US-OEM  2016-02 21  3267732.17
```

Comment: Please tag your question with the database you are using.

Answer (score 0):

You can use an aggregation query with `case`:

```
select (case when col2 in ('Commercial', 'Non-commercial') then 'Commercial'
             when col2 in ('OEM', 'CA-OEM') then 'OEM'
             else 'col2'
        end),
       sum(col4) as col4
from t
group by (case when col2 in ('Commercial', 'Non-commercial') then 'Commercial'
               when col2 in ('OEM', 'CA-OEM') then 'OEM'
               else 'col2'
          end);
```

Comment: Is there a way to select a date range?  For example SELECT TRX_DATE (FORMAT 'YYYY-MM') (CHAR(7)) AS BATCH_DATE_MONTH 
WHERE CAST(TRX_DATE AS DATE FORMAT 'mm/dd/yyyy') >= '02-01-2016'

Comment: @WasimGreaves . . . If you have another question, it should be asked as a question and not in a comment.  You should include sample data, desired results, any query you have, and properly tag the question with the database you are using.